# Bottom Navigation in Android works only on double clicks ,

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Creating an app ,and  implementing the bottom navigation through setting up the "On navigation selected listener",On clicking the icons in the bottom nav panel , i am trying to replace fragments, The fragments do get replaced but on double clicks. A single click on the menu item does nothing.
Here is my Code
'''

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   // val toolbar=app_bar as androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

 val navigation = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as BottomNavigationView
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {

        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {

                var x = supportFragmentManager
                var y = x.beginTransaction()

                var fragment = HomeFragment()
                y.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                y.addToBackStack("123")
                y.commit()


            }

            R.id.navigation_login -> {

                var x = supportFragmentManager
                var y = x.beginTransaction()

                var fragment = LoginFragment()
                y.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                y.addToBackStack("456")
                y.commit()


            }

            R.id.navigation_notifactory -> {

                var x = supportFragmentManager
                var y = x.beginTransaction()

                var fragment = NotificationFragment()
                y.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                y.addToBackStack("789")
                y.commit()


            }




        }

    }


    var x = supportFragmentManager
    var y = x.beginTransaction()

    val fragment=HomeFragment()

    y.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment)
    y.addToBackStack(null)
    y.commit()
}



}
```

'''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this :

```
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
```

by:

```
   navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using   navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener. its reselect the select the item and than select it .thats the reason you have to press two time for selecting the item. remove this and set  `navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Answer (score 0):

my solution is, if is check is not correct I don't take action

```
binding.bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            if (!binding.bottomNav.menu.findItem(it.itemId).isChecked) navController.navigate(it.itemId)
            true

    }
```